# Drawing vector addition

Tags: python

Lets say I have the following arrays which contain the X and Y values for a bunch of vectors, respectively:

```python
xdat = np.array([3,2,7,4])
ydat = np.array([2,4,4,9])
```

Lets say that I wanted to draw the sum total of these vectors (a+b+c+d), not only as a single line from the origin, but drawn sequentially from the sum of each individual vector.

How do I do this?

My idea is to use plt.plot for the values of two new arrays which contain the X and Y coordinates for each start/end point of all the vectors. The specific coordinates would be calculated from xdat and ydat. Assuming this was the most efficient method (without resorting to some easy-to-use function already built into python) how would I code this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you want [`numpy.cumsum`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.cumsum.html)

```
import numpy as np

xdat = np.array([3,2,7,4])
ydat = np.array([2,4,4,9])

dat = np.vstack((xdat, ydat))
# array([[3, 2, 7, 4],
#        [2, 4, 4, 9]])

dat = np.cumsum(dat, axis=1)
# array([[ 3,  5, 12, 16],
#        [ 2,  6, 10, 19]], dtype=int32)

# optionally start at 0, 0 (can do this before or after cumsum)
dat = np.hstack([np.zeros((2, 1)), dat])
# array([[  0.,   3.,   5.,  12.,  16.],
#        [  0.,   2.,   6.,  10.,  19.]])
```

I stacked them up for convenience, but you could also run `cumsum` on the 1-D arrays.  The `axis` argument selects either to run over the whole flattened array (`None`, the default), or along the n-th axis (row = `0`, column = `1`)

If you want to plot the X-Y coordinates, I'd do so with `plt.plot(*dat)`, which will unpack the X and Y rows as arguments to plot.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work as I was hoping to. Just for argument's sake, let's say I have two vectors with coordinates (0,2) and (4,0) respectively. Adding these two vectors would give me a diagonal line corresponding to (4,2).

Now to represent this in python, I would have:
xdat = np.array([0,4])
ydat = np.array([2,0])

dat = np.vstack((xdat, ydat))

dat = np.cumsum(dat, axis=1)
plt.plot(*dat)

Following your code, this ends up giving me a series of two lines connected from (0,0) to (1,2) to (4,0).
More accurately, it should draw lines from (0,0) to (0,2) to (4,2).

Comment: @user155876 did you try my code; it works. Print out the array you have and see if it's what you expect.