# Plotting vector addition?

Tags: python

Straight to the point:

[image: vector images]

Lets say I have a bunch of vectors A, B and C and their horizontal and vertical components are split into two arrays respectively:

```python
xdat = np.array([x1,x2,x3])
ydat = np.array([y1,y2,y3])
```

I want to:

1. Plot each individual vector from the data given in the arrays
2. Plot the sequential vector additions
3. Plot the sum vector A+B+C

I'm fairly new to python so this stuff is difficult for me. I tried plotting 1 by simply doing plt.plot(xdat,ydat) but the figure I get looks wrong. Ideally, I'd like to learn the general method for this stuff which can apply to N number of vectors.

Comment: So your vectors are `A=(x1,y1), B=(x2,y2), C=(x3,y3)`?

Comment: That was just filler - replace them with any arbitrary real number.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Drawing vector addition](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26375898/drawing-vector-addition)

Comment: maybe useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12265234/plotting-2d-vectors-in-python-matplotlib

Comment: Yeah Carsten, it is a duplicate of that. However, in that question I don't think I properly conveyed the full scope of what I was trying to achieve - that and the answer from the person who replied did not seem correct either. Now that I posted this newer question which seems a lot more coherent, I tried to delete the old one but the presence of any answers in a question prevents me from doing that without moderator assistance.

Comment: Your image doesn't show vector A+B, it shows B being translated by A. Similar for C. The green line isn't A+B+C. It is just C translated by A+B.

Answer (score 0):

The following code prints a vector sum knowing one of the components and the total.. you can easily adapt it to your specific user case..

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plotVectorChart_inner(origin,end1,endt,xlabel,ylabel,filename):
 a=plt.figure()
 ax = plt.gca()
 fig = plt.gcf()
 flag_2d = True
 if(origin[0] == end1[0] == endt[0]):
   flag_2d = False;
   fig.set_size_inches(6,10)
 else:
   fig.set_size_inches(10,10)
 end2 = (endt[0]-end1[0]+origin[0],endt[1]-end1[1]+origin[1])
 minx = min(origin[0],end1[0],end2[0],endt[0])
 maxx = max(origin[0],end1[0],end2[0],endt[0])
 miny = min(origin[1],end1[1],end2[1],endt[1])
 maxy = max(origin[1],end1[1],end2[1],endt[1])
 centre = (((maxx-minx)/2)+minx,((maxy-miny)/2)+miny)
 X  = (origin[0], origin[0], origin[0])
 Y  = (origin[1], origin[1], origin[1])
 X2 = (end1[0]-origin[0], endt[0]-origin[0], end2[0]-origin[0]) 
 Y2 = (end1[1]-origin[1], endt[1]-origin[1], end2[1]-origin[1])
 C  = (255,010,150) # ? colour codes, but didn't got it

 ax.quiver(X,Y,X2,Y2,C,angles='xy',scale_units='xy',scale=1, width=0.008)
 x  = (end1[0],end2[0])
 y  = (end1[1],end2[1])
 x2 = (endt[0]-end1[0], endt[0]-end2[0])
 y2 = (endt[1]-end1[1], endt[1]-end2[1])

 if(flag_2d):
   ax.quiver(x,y,x2,y2,angles='xy',scale_units='xy',scale=1, width=0.005, color='gray')
   ax.set_xlim([minx- (centre[0]-minx)*0.4, maxx + (maxx-centre[0])*0.4])

 ax.set_ylim([miny- (centre[1]-miny)*0.4, maxy + (maxy-centre[1])*0.4])

 plt.xlabel(unicode(xlabel, 'utf_8'))
 plt.ylabel(unicode(ylabel, 'utf_8'))
 # Uncomment the following lines if you want to display instead of save the figure..
 #plt.draw()
 #plt.show()
 plt.savefig(filename, dpi=300)

plotVectorChart_inner((9.791,1609),(9.441,5489),(9.760,4645),"Area [M sq.km]", "Volume [M c.m.]","vol_area_broadL.png")
plotVectorChart_inner((4.317,926),(4.667,1943),(4.349,1510),"Area [M sq.km]", "Volume [M c.m.]","vol_area_con.png")
plotVectorChart_inner((14.108,2535),(14.108,7432),(14.108,6155),"Area [M sq.km]", "Volume [M c.m.]","vol_area_tot.png")
```

This generate a figure like this one:
[image: output]